# What Is The Difference Between Using Wildcard Mask In EIGRP And In OSPF?

Tags: ospf, eigrp

I noticed that in the CBT learning videos, a lot of teachers ignored using the wildcard mask when configuring the EIGRP, however, they always used it when they configured OSPF. I looked on the internet to know why that was, but I could not understand the explanations there. I only knew that it was almost a must to use it in the case of OSPF.

**What is the difference?**

Update:

More precisely:

**What would happen if we ignore configuring the wildcard make in both cases (iegrp, ospf)?*

[EIGRP Packet Trace Routing Lab Example](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qsarPElfqa8KwRYwmfMMkxkfyKS_4Qea/view?usp=sharing).

Configuration Sample:

```
R02(config)#do sh ip protocol

Routing Protocol is "eigrp  22 " 
  Outgoing update filter list for all interfaces is not set 
  Incoming update filter list for all interfaces is not set 
  Default networks flagged in outgoing updates  
  Default networks accepted from incoming updates 
  Redistributing: eigrp 22
  EIGRP-IPv4 Protocol for AS(22)
    Metric weight K1=1, K2=0, K3=1, K4=0, K5=0
    NSF-aware route hold timer is 240
    Router-ID: 192.168.0.109
    Topology : 0 (base)
      Active Timer: 3 min
      Distance: internal 90 external 170
      Maximum path: 4
      Maximum hopcount 100
      Maximum metric variance 1

  Automatic Summarization: disabled
  Automatic address summarization: 
  Maximum path: 4
  Routing for Networks:  
     192.168.0.0
  Routing Information Sources:  
    Gateway         Distance      Last Update 
    192.168.0.110   90            1013492133 
    192.168.0.117   90            1013492136 
  Distance: internal 90 external 170
```

---

```
R02(config)#do sh ip rout
Codes: L - local, C - connected, S - static, R - RIP, M - mobile, B - BGP
       D - EIGRP, EX - EIGRP external, O - OSPF, IA - OSPF inter area
       N1 - OSPF NSSA external type 1, N2 - OSPF NSSA external type 2
       E1 - OSPF external type 1, E2 - OSPF external type 2, E - EGP
       i - IS-IS, L1 - IS-IS level-1, L2 - IS-IS level-2, ia - IS-IS inter area
       * - candidate default, U - per-user static route, o - ODR
       P - periodic downloaded static route

Gateway of last resort is not set

     192.168.0.0/24 is variably subnetted, 12 subnets, 3 masks
D       192.168.0.16/28 [90/5376] via 192.168.0.110, 03:16:45, GigabitEthernet0/1
D       192.168.0.32/28 [90/5632] via 192.168.0.117, 03:16:45, GigabitEthernet0/2
D       192.168.0.48/28 [90/5888] via 192.168.0.110, 03:16:45, GigabitEthernet0/1
C       192.168.0.104/29 is directly connected, GigabitEthernet0/1
L       192.168.0.109/32 is directly connected, GigabitEthernet0/1
C       192.168.0.112/29 is directly connected, GigabitEthernet0/2
L       192.168.0.118/32 is directly connected, GigabitEthernet0/2
D       192.168.0.120/29 [90/3072] via 192.168.0.117, 03:16:45, GigabitEthernet0/2
D       192.168.0.128/29 [90/3072] via 192.168.0.110, 03:16:45, GigabitEthernet0/1
D       192.168.0.136/29 [90/3328] via 192.168.0.110, 03:16:45, GigabitEthernet0/1
D       192.168.0.144/29 [90/3584] via 192.168.0.117, 03:16:45, GigabitEthernet0/2
                         [90/3584] via 192.168.0.110, 03:16:45, GigabitEthernet0/1
D       192.168.0.152/29 [90/3328] via 192.168.0.117, 03:16:45, GigabitEthernet0/2
```

---

```
R02(config)#do sh run
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 777 bytes
!
version 15.1
no service timestamps log datetime msec
no service timestamps debug datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname R02
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
ip cef
no ipv6 cef
!
!
!
!
license udi pid CISCO2911/K9 sn FTX1524PI2Z-
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
spanning-tree mode pvst
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 no ip address
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 shutdown
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 ip address 192.168.0.109 255.255.255.248
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/2
 ip address 192.168.0.118 255.255.255.248
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
router eigrp 22
 network 192.168.0.0
!
ip classless
!
ip flow-export version 9
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
line con 0
 exec-timeout 0 0
!
line aux 0
!
line vty 0 4
 login
!
!
!
end
```

and Here is the Network Topology:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll assume you are referring to the wildcard mask being used with the `network ...` statements in EIGRP and OSPF configurations.

As in (pseudo config code)

```
router ospf 100
 router-id <some32bitIntegerInDottedDecimalNotation>
 network 192.168.0.1 0.0.0.0 area <AREA ID> 
 network 192.168.0.129 0.0.0.0 area <AREA ID>

interface gig0/1
 ip address 192.168.0.1 255.255.225.192
 [...]

interface gig0/2
 ip address 192.168.0.129 255.255.225.224
 [...]
```

For OSPF and EIGRP, there must be a definition which IP interfaces of the router should be active for the routing protocol.

Classically, this is done using the `network` statement with a wildcard mask: All IP interfaces on the router are checked against the *network & wildcard mask* statements.

If there is a match, the interface with that IP address will become an active interface for the routing protocol (cf `show ip ospf|eigrp interface brief`), and it will start "talking" OSPF (EIGRP, respectively). It will make itself known by sending out OSPF/EIGRP hello packets, will attempt to discover neighbors and establish adjacencies, and eventually exchange routing information with the the neighbors.

It is very important to understand that *network statement & wildcard mask* are independent from *interface IP address & subnet mask*:

> **Please note:** Only the interface's *IP address* is checked against the
> wildcard mask; the interface's subnet mask is not checked.
>
> It is perfectly correct, even desirable, to have...
>
> `192.168.0.1 255.255.255.192` on the interface    and
>
> `192.168.0.1 0.0.0.0` in the routing protocol's network statement
>
> The network & wildcard mask statement only and exlusively has the
> purpose of defining those interfaces/IP addresses which should speak
> EIGRP/OSPF to their neighbors on a link.
>
> It has no function of a "route filter" to select which IP addresses of
> an attached subnet are being advertised by OSPF or EIGRP to the other
> routers.
>
> Once an interface is defined as active interface, OSPF/EIRP will
> look at the subnet mask from the interface configuration, and will >
> determine from that what to tell it's neighbors, not from the
> wildcard mask.
>
> In the example here, `network 192.168.0.1 0.0.0.0` will  make the router's
> interface with the IP 192.168.0.1 an active interface, but EIGRP/OSFP will tell
> the other routers that there is a network/subnet of `192.168.0.0 255.255.255.192`
> in the routing domain.
>
> There can be multiple `network...` statements, of course, and by using
> the host mask `0.0.0.0`, you can get detailed control over which
> interface(s) of a router are active speakers.  Using large wildcard
> masks might activate the routing protocol on interfaces where it's not
> needed or undesirable, possibly causing various kinds of side effects.

The independence between *IP address & subnet mask* and *network statement & wildard mask* can also be illustraded by looking at the more modern config styles, where network statements don't exist anymore.

In a more modern style for OSPF, you can activate an interface for OSPF directly in interface configuration mode, like (again, pseudo config code):

```
router ospf 100
 router-id <some32bitIntegerInDottedDecimalNotation>

interface gig0/0
 ip address 192.168.0.1 255.255.255.192
 ip ospf 100 area <AREA ID>
```

(please note: Unfortunately, the same is not possible for EIGRP for IPv4).

In IPv6, for both OSPF and EIGRP, the interfaces to be active for the routing protocol are exclusively defined in the modern per-interface configuration style.

So you may want to check if the CBT examples you are referring to ...

- have a single large subnet & wildcard-mask statement in the router's configuration, which just so happens to match all IP interfaces of the given router [1]
- use the more modern per-interface configuration style

**To provide a direct answer:**

No difference. For both OSPF and EIGRP, the `network ...` statement defines which interfaces of the router should be considered relevant to the routing protocol.

If an interface's IP address matches the wildcard mask, the interface will start "talking the routing protocol" (unless configured to be a `passive-interface`, but that's another topic)

**If ignoring/omitting the network statement**

If you omit/ignore the network statement, and if you do not use any other means to define the interfaces to be active: The routing protocol will be configured and active, but the router will not attempt to discover neighbors and wil not try talking to them, and of course will not exchange routing information with them.

**Omitting the wildcard mask in network statement**

If you omit the wildcard mask, the network statement is interpreted as if having the classful mask pertaining to the IP address.

```
192.168.0.0 is read as 192.168.0.0 0.0.0.255
172.19.0.0  is read as 172.19.0.0 0.0.255.255
etc.
```

So here we stumble over a configuration fossil from the ages of classful networking. "Network Classes are long dead, obsoleted in 1993" as @Zac67 often puts it. Still, every so often, we find bits of it.

---

[1] basic config examples found on the web often match the wildcard masks in network statements with the interface subnet masks, or they bluntly use large wildcard masks. While not actually wrong, I think this is suboptimal practice especially for novices, because it somewhat obfuscates what is actually happening. Also, later on in the learning curve, it makes it more difficult to understand how the network & mask statement in BGP configuration has a fundamentally differend meaning.

Comment: Good answer. The only thing I would add is that there is probably just some factor of the preference of the people who developed the original implementation and then historical inertia that kept it that way until someone decided to do things differently with more recent implementations. It boils down to how it was done first and then how people didn't want to change it because they are used to doing it that way.

Comment: @Marc'netztier'Luethi Thanks, but I am not sure this addresses my question precisely. I know the benefit of the wildcard mask. But what is the difference if it is not configured? see the updated question. can we even ignore it in ospf as I am sure we can do in eigrp?

Comment: `I am sure we can do in eigrp? `  Can you please provide an example/source for that?

Comment: @Marc'netztier'Luethi [This is A Packet Tracer EIRGP Lab](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qsarPElfqa8KwRYwmfMMkxkfyKS_4Qea/view?usp=share_link) that was created without using wildcard masks.

Comment: @Shadi i don't have (nor want to run) packet tracer;  can you please edit the question to include your source? Add quoted text if at all possible, screenshots only if there's no alternative. Other than tha:  network statements without an explicit wildcard mask will implicitely use the classful mask matching the address class. Once more, the demon of classful adressing comes to haunt us....

Comment: @Marc'netztier'Luethi I updated the question with the topology and some configuration samples from Router R02.

Comment: Thanks for the update to the question.  As I surmised: There *is* a `network ... ` statement, lack ing the wildcard mask. It therefore defaults to the classful mask matching its address class: that statement is actually `192.168.0.0 0.0.0.255`.  That you got confused by thelack of the wildcard mask supports my point that novices are better off by specifying each to-be-active interface indivually with a interface address and host wildcard mask (e.g. 192.168.0.118 0.0.0.0) or using interface based configuration from the start.

Comment: @Marc'netztier'Luethi I see. I know no difference in use and meaning. However, it seems if we have the command network 192.168.0.0 without wildcard mask it will default to network 192.168.0.0 0.0.0.255 in case of eigrp, and to network 192.168.0.0 0.0.0.0 in case of ospf, which will allow more networks in the case of eigrp and ban all networks in the case of ospf. so the behavior **is different** when we ignore the wildcard mas. Correct? If yes, I hope that you reflect this in your answer in more obvious way as I want to accept it. Thank you for your great help and for the rich info.

Comment: I also understand now that eigrp defaults to one of the following 0.255.255.255, 0.0.255.255, or 0.0.0.255 as in our example. It depends on the class of the subnet. this is why it should be 0.0.0.7 or 0.0.0.15 in our example depending on the subnet mask. Correct?

Comment: I would be surprised if  `network 192.168.0.0` would default to 192.168.0.0 0.0.0.0 for  OSPF and to 192.168.0.0 0.0.0.255 for EIRGP.   You can easily check, by doing `show ip eigrp interface brief` or `show ip ospf interface brief` after setting the network statement. These commands will list the interfaces that are considered "active" for the routing protocol.

Comment: `this is why it should be 0.0.0.7 or 0.0.0.15 in our example depending on the subnet mask. Correct?` not incorrect at least. Read the footnote 1 in my answer. There is no need to correlate the wildcard mask in the network statement with the subnet mask on the interface.  Making them equal/equivalent is not wrong, but it implies a correlation which does not exist.

Comment: @Marc'netztier'Luethi It is correct considering that we want to pass all the traffic for all possible IPs per subnet. However, I understand you are correct if we want to control the traffic more granularly. for example if we want to limit eigrp traffic between R0 and R04 we could use the following command: `network 192.168.0.133 0.0.0.2` instead of 192.168.0.128 0.0.0.7.

Comment: `It is correct considering that we want to pass all the traffic for all possible IPs per subnet.` Sorry, still wrong.  You are still mixing up *wildcard mask in network statement* with *subnet mask on interface*. They are independent of each other. In OSPF and EIGRP, the network statement's address and wildcard mask only define which IP address resp. interface should be an actively "talking" OSPF resp. EIGRP interface. Once that interface is active, its subnet (incl. correct subnet mask) will in become part of the OSPF or EIGRP topology, and the other routers will learn about it.

Comment: @Marc'netztier'Luethi Thank you for your thorough, informative, and precise answer. After many labs, I can now see it clearly. I could not ignore the wildcard mask in the case of OSPF at least in my packet tracer lab. Any how your answer is precise and informative. Thanks for the time and effort.